# Scrapy scrapes till 8 page and then just crawls

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, scraper

I'm making a web crawler with scrapy and I get the info I want but only for the first 8 pages after that it just crawls every page with out getting any data

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class InfoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "info"
    start_urls = [
        'http://dounai-lavein.gr/catalog/cat/cars/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('div.item-featured',)),
            callback="parse",
            follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.item-featured'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('div.item-title a h3::text').extract_first(),
                'owner': quote.css('div.entry-content p.txtrows-4::text').extract(),
                'address': quote.css('.item-address span.value::text').extract_first(),
                'web_address': quote.css('.item-web span.value a::attr(href)').extract(),
                'image_link': quote.css('.item-image img').xpath("@src").extract_first()[0]
            }

        next_page = response.css('span.nav-next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Found it thank you . Ichose wrong selector

Answer (score 0):

Page 9 and the following of the site you are scraping do not have the class *item-featured* any more.
Try with this:

```
    ...
    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('div.item-container',)),
        callback="parse",
        follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.item-container'):
            yield {
            ...
```